# How to check if a variable is the same as at least one of two other variables?

Tags: python, equality

I have a variable, and want to check if it matches at least one of the other two variables.

Clearly I can do:

```
if a == b or a == c:
```

But I want to know if there is any shorter way, something like:

```
if a == (b or c):
```

How to test if a variable is the same as - at least - one of the others?

Comment: You should rephrase the question. Currently it implies you want `if a == b and a == c`

Comment: @TimCastelijns: I edited it, hopefully that was what you meant. Also it wasn't me who phrased the question; someone other edited my initial post to the misleading question

Comment: I see, it's a shame that other edit got through the review. Thanks for editing

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For that use `in`:

```
if a in (b, c):
```

Testing for membership in a `tuple` has an average case of `O(n)` time complexity. If you have a large collection of values and are performing many membership tests on the same collection of values, it may be worth creating a `set` for speed:

```
x = set((b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,...))
if a in x:
    ...
if y in x:
    ...
```

Once it has been constructed, testing for membership in the `set` has an average case of `O(1)` time complexity, so it is potentially faster in the long run.

Or, you can also do:

```
if any(a == i for i in (b,c)):
```

Comment: Your point about time complexity is invalid as it neglects the cost of constructing the `set` from the tuple, which appears to grow linearly with the length of the tuple. If you are concerned about time, you should use `a in (b, c)`.

Comment: @TomFenech, Oh right! Thank you. Completely missed that. I am updating my answer.

Comment: I have reworded the explanation a bit. Feel free to roll it back if you don't like it.

Comment: @TomFenech, You said in a few lines, 100 times more clearly than what I was saying in 20. Thank you so much!